# Which type library hosts stdDataFormat?

Tags: visual-c++, com, vb6

I am trying to import VB6's `VBRUN` type library into a Visual C++ 2017 header file, but it is failing due to a missing dependency.

Visual C++ reports

> "error C4772: #import referenced a type from a missing type library;
> '**missing_type**' used as a placeholder"

Viewing the file with OLE View reveals the problem is with the `DataFormat` property `(DataFormat([out, retval] --<GetRefTypeInfo failed>** Return))`.

The missing dependency would appear to be `stdDataFormat`: which type library does `stdDataFormat` reside in and why is it missing? (My operating system is Windows 10 Enterprise, 21H1.) Did I miss a selection when installing Visual Studio 6?

Comment: I've just done a quick scan of my W10 64-bit Windows folder and, apart from a few Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.data.dll files in the .NET folders, the only one containing that text string is MSSTDFMT.DLL in the C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder. The file description is "Microsoft Standard Data Formatting Object DLL" and that file is also in my W7 Windows\System32 folder. Both systems have VB6 installed on them.

Comment: A clue about MSSTDMFMT.DLL. The [Microsoft VB6 support statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/visual-basic-6-support-policy#supported-runtime-files-to-distribute-with-your-application) lists this DLL under 'Supported runtime files to distribute with your application'. So it is part of the VB6 runtime. Did you install the Visual Basic 6 IDE on the PC? I would guess that installation will provide the DLL

Comment: It's also part of _(at least)_ the Visual Studio Service Pack 6, in the archive VS6sp61.cab, to be precise

Comment: Type libraries host nothing, there is no code there at all.  They are really just a form of precompiled source code, an input to an IDE or compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This addresses the first part of the question, how to find the typelib (TLB) containing a given interface or class.

---

Assuming you have no preconception about the TLB / DLL hosting a given COM interface or class you can find it by a couple of registry searches, assuming the type in question actually has been registered.

I started off in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` with a search for data values = `stdDataFormat`. This lead to:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSSTDFMT.StdDataFormat]
@="StdDataFormat Object"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSSTDFMT.StdDataFormat\CLSID]
@="{6D835690-900B-11D0-9484-00A0C91110ED}"
```

Now armed with the CLSID GUID of `6D835690-900B-11D0-9484-00A0C91110ED`, search for that value, finding:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{6D835690-900B-11D0-9484-00A0C91110ED
```

of which its important sub-element for our purposes is:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{6D835690-900B-11D0-9484-00A0C91110ED}\InprocServer32]
@="c:\\windows\\SysWow64\\msstdfmt.dll"
...
```

The **`InprocServer32`** value was the main thing I wanted to find; it tells you the DLL - which is `c:\windows\SysWow64\msstdfmt.dll` (on my PC - but this should be typical).

Opening `msstdfmt.dll` in OLEView (or [OLEViewDotNet](https://github.com/tyranid/oleviewdotnet)) confirms this; the decompiled IDL from the TLB in that DLL contains:

```
[
  uuid(6D835690-900B-11D0-9484-00A0C91110ED),
  helpstring("StdDataFormat Object"),
  helpcontext(0x00066b5f)
]
coclass StdDataFormat {
    [default] interface IStdDataFormatDisp;
    [default, source] dispinterface IStdDataFormatEvents;
};
```

So `msstdfmt.dll` should be the missing dependency.

If you did suspect this DLL to begin with, then obviously its a lot quicker to just load it in OLEView and check. But in many cases that won't be obvious when you're starting out.

---

As for the second part of the question - why is this dependency missing - maybe it would help if you added the relevant section of your code / includes?

Comment: Code is #import "MSVBVM60.DLL" tlbid(3). Shouldn't the dependency be found automatically?

Comment: I don't think MSVBVM60.DLL actually has a dependency on MSSTDFMT. Looking in its TLB, there is no reference to it nor to `StdDataFormat`.  In contrast, MSVBVM60 does have a dependencey on STDOLE (for example) and that shows up as a `importlib("stdole2.tlb")` in the TLB. There's no equivalent for MSSTDFMT.

Comment: The line behind my grief shows in the MSVBVM60 IDL as "HRESULT DataFormat([out, retval] <GetRefTypeInfo failed>** Return);".

Comment: RJ when I look in the TLB for MSVBVM60 I don't see anything containing "DataFormat". I'm looking at the file in SysWOW64. It is version 6.0.98.48.

Comment: BTW Did you try to manually import the MSSTDFMT DLL?

Comment: Yes, I can manually import MSSTTFMT.DLL.